# how to use TFS SDK to fetch the list of hyperlinked documents from a workitem

Tags: tfs

How do I use TFS sdk to get the list of hyperlink names that are linked to a tfs workitem.

Currently I can see only 1 property HyperLinkCount which just gets me the count of hyperlinks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `Links` property of the `WorkItem`.

The links of type `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Hyperlink` are the ones you are after, you can get them like so:

```
var hyperLinks = 
    workItemStore
    .GetWorkItem(12345)
    .Links
    .OfType<Hyperlink>();
```